# How to highlight the highest values on bar graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to emphasize the highest value on a bar graph using ggplot2. After successfully generating the clustered bar graph and integrating count labels on the bars, I tried to highlight the maximum value using the `annotate()` function. However, I encountered alignment issues. How can I address this?

here is the code I'm using:

```
library(ggplot2)

data <- read.csv("D:\\Athira\\Elephant\\eleph_count\\distance\\distance_st.csv")
data$Distance <- factor(data$Distance, levels = c("0-5", "5-10", "10-50", "50-100", ">100"))
ggplot(data, aes(Distance, Count, fill = State)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.90, colour = "black") +
  labs(x = "Distance (Km)", y = "Count") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(
    "Andra Pradesh" = "#00798c",
    "Assam" = "#d1495b",
    "Jharkhand" = "#edae49",
    "Maharashtra" = "#66a182",
    "Nagaland" = "#2e4057",
    "Odisha" = "yellow",
    "Tamil Nadu" = "blue"
  )) +
  geom_text(data = data_filtered, aes(label = Count), color = "black", size = 3, vjust = -0.30,
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.90), hjust = 0.8) +
  annotate("text", x = max_values$Distance, y = max_values$Count + 1,  # Adjusted y-coordinate
           label = max_values$Count, color = "red", size = 3, vjust = 0.8, hjust = -2.9) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    text = element_text(size = 10.5),
    axis.text.x = element_text(color = "black", size = 10),
    axis.text.y = element_text(color = "black", size = 10)
  )
```

This give me a graph like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can change the colour of the text in geom_text as:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

x <- rnorm(100, 100, 20) %>% round()
x_cat <- cut(x, breaks = 6, include.lowest = TRUE)
x_df <- x_cat %>% table() %>% data.frame() %>% 
  rename(Category = 1, Count = 2) %>%
  mutate(Top = ifelse(Count < sort(Count, decreasing = TRUE)[3], FALSE, TRUE))

ggplot(data=x_df, aes(x=Category, y = Count, fill = Category)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label=Count, col = Top), vjust=-0.5)
```

I hope this helps.[image]

Answer (score 0):

`annotate` is meant to add small or single annotations to a plot. Instead, if you want to add labels based on your data use a `geom_text` as you already did but add a variable to your data indicating the maximum counts. This new variable can then be mapped on the `color` aes to highlight the top counts where you can set your desired colors using `scale_color_manual`. Also note, that when doing so we have to explicitly map on the `group` aes to group and dodge the labels by `State` only.

Using some fake example data based on the `ggplot2::mpg` dataset:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

# Example data
data <- mpg |>
  rename(State = class, Distance = cty) |>
  mutate(Distance = cut_number(Distance,
    n = 5,
    labels = c("0-5", "5-10", "10-50", "50-100", ">100")
  )) |>
  count(State, Distance, name = "Count")

data$Distance <- factor(data$Distance,
  levels = c("0-5", "5-10", "10-50", "50-100", ">100")
)

data <- data |> 
  mutate(
    is_max_count = Count %in% max(Count), .by = Distance
  )

ggplot(data, aes(Distance, Count, fill = State)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge", width = 0.90, colour = "black") +
  labs(x = "Distance (Km)", y = "Count") +
  geom_text(
    aes(
      label = Count,
      color = is_max_count,
      group = State
    ),
    size = 3, vjust = -0.30,
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.90),
    show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c("black", "red")
  ) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    text = element_text(size = 10.5),
    axis.text = element_text(color = "black", size = 10)
  )
```

[image]